# Calling of Nested Modules in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been recently working on a project with 150+ files and I am faced with a big hurdle in the switching modules.

I have a feature which allows switching of modules. It works in the following way (I am giving a simplified explanation):

Suppose there are 4 files as `first.py`, `second.py`, `third.py`, `fourth.py` and each of the following file has a module same as its filename which calls its previous function as below.

Content of `first.py`

```
from second import *
def first():
    second()
```

Content of `second.py`

```
from third import *
def second():
    third()
```

Content of `third.py`:

```
from fourth import *
def third():
    q = raw_input('Use (f)ourth or go (b)ack?') 
        if q == 'f':
            fourth() # proceed to fourth
        elif q == 'b':
            second() # back to second module
# this is how the switching of modules work
```

Content of `fourth.py`:

```
def fourth():
    <stuff1>
```

Now when `first()` is called, the interpreter asks for `f or b`. If `f`, then the `<stuff1>` is executed, but when `b` is the input, it gives a `NameError` something like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 4, in <module>
    first()
  File "first.py", line 3, in first
    second()
  File "test/second.py", line 3, in second
    third()
  File "test/third.py", line 7, in third
    second()
NameError: global name 'second' is not defined
```

And this is basically how the switching back of modules is failing. I have tried importing `second.py` in third file by adding `from second import second` which did not help but instead put out an ImportError as `ImportError: cannot import name second`. Declaring `function names` as `global variables` too did not help.

Is there a any way how i can achieve this. Or there is a more efficient way to solve the switching problem.

**Edit:**
I understand that a circular dependency is being created, but is there any other way to getting the 4 modules up and running without creating this circular dependency.

Comment: Do they really need to be in separate modules?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for your quick reply. If you go through the [source code](https://github.com/theinfecteddrake/tidos-framework), you can see there are 150+ files present. I guess there is no other way.. :(

Comment: Hmm, smells like a design problem. You have a circular dep between 2nd and 3rd.  I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve and why you chose this way. A quick thought is joining the 2 modules or split them differently so you don't have the circular dep.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do something like this aside - you're creating a circular dependency here. How can the Python interpreter import your module which depends on another module which itself depends on the first module - no import can ever be completed in this setting? I'd rethink the design if I were you.

Comment: @CristiFati , can you please elaborate on how I would proceed with that. i am looking for ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @The-InfectedDrake - You have a design problem, not a code problem. Without knowing what is your end goal we cannot provide you with any meaningful suggestion.

Comment: Ooo, I also see circular deps at function level as well. Starting from existing code, getting rid of *second.py* would seem the shortest way (also modify 1st accordingly).

Comment: @CristiFati , sadly i cannot remove the second module. If you go through the entire [framework source](https://github.com/theinfecteddrake/tidos-framework), you will probably understand why i can't. :(

Comment: Of course you can _remove the second module_ - redesign the system so it doesn't have circular dependencies. You have the code (based on your nick I'd assume you're the project's owner, too) so you can literally do anything with it. Now, how would you do it, and where is the actual problem is a whole different question - surely you don't expect us to go through all of that code to tell you everything that's wrong with it, right? There is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in the Stack Exchange network intended for such questions...

Comment: @zwer I got you :) I was just looking out a way to get through without removing any module/sub module.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me to be a **circular import**. 
The problem is between **second.py** and **third.py**. You invoke **third** in **second.py** and then **second** in **third.py**. 
You can read [this article](http://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/) to find out what circular imports are and how to prevent them.

P.S. I would suggest not using this syntax for importing stuff from other modules.

```
from ... import *
```

This can produce name conflicts and you don't know what is inside this module. 
Better option is to import the only things you need or to refer to a specific functions of a module.